# Clear/Overwrite css for a input element

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I have a problem styling my form. Everything works fine except the checkboxes. They look very strange. Have a look at the small rectangle, this is how it looks like when I place a checkbox in my html:

```
<input id="check" type="checkbox" name="test" value="test"/>
```

[image]

The strange thing is, if I remove my css it does not change. Is there a basic css configuration for a checkbox to make it look like a standart checkbox? I tried things like

```
#check{background: white !important}
```

but it does not work.

Any other advice?

Comment: I can't imagine you've provided enough code to diagnose this. Maybe make a jsFiddle page with the code so we can see a more complete version of the page.

Comment: Could you provide a live link (something like http://jsfiddle.net) so we can see the actual CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that the default styling from the browser or you have something like

```
* { margin: 0; padding: 0 }
```

in your CSS code? If so... than that's what's causing the default behavior to be removed and is very hard to put back.